# Vue js how to iterate of an Object of Objects to access and display details of elements inside it from the html tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for-loop

Good day developers.In this shop cart im framing got a little issue  about iterating over an object of objects i got as final result once i add the products to the cart and group then by names.
Basically using a reduce function i conglomerate all products of same type(name) in its respective groups.
But them trying to loop on this groups from my html tag in order to reach to the name , or price , has being unsuccessful.
 here what i have done:

First a sample of my Json Object:

```
{
  "Chucky": [
    {
      "product_name": "Chucky",
      "product_price": 153.4
    },
    {
      "product_name": "Chucky",
      "product_price": 153.4
    }
  ],
  "Glasses": [
    {
      "product_name": "Glasses",
      "product_price": 10.4
    },
    {
      "product_name": "Glasses",
      "product_price": 10.4
    }
  ]
}
```

then on my html tag i declare an iteration over this object , in order to conform a card for each of these groups of elements , pretending to access to the name and the price.
Lets say

```
<template>
    <v-container>

        <v-container
          v-for="(item, key,index) in  groupProds " :key="index">
           <v-card >
               <h3 style="font-size:10px;margin-left:10px;">{{item[0].product_name}}</h3>
               <h3 style="font-size:14px;margin-left:10px;width:200px;">Price: ${{item[0].product_price}}</h3>

.......More code
```

But there'snt way any result shows but only the cards with no information

[image]

Any advice about how could i improve this for better way?
Thanks in advance!!!And have a good day!!

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/r0qgs6ou/

Comment: thanks Twharmon , should be another problem on my  code . Thanks